# methods of storing session in redis using spring

Tags: java, spring, session, redis

I am in dilemma to store session in redis using Spring and there are many methods and concepts to handle this issue. Some methods are listed below:

1. Spring Data Redis
2. Spring Session
3. Spring Session Manager

Now the question is what is the best combination to store (delete and so on) session in redis using spring.

I will be appreciated if someone help me with a simple explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You're a little confused:

> - [Spring Data Redis](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-redis/) provides easy configuration and access to Redis from any type of Spring applications. It realize both low-level and high-level abstractions for interacting with the Redis store. In few words - just realization of Redis client library.
> - [Spring Session](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#introduction) provides an API and implementations for managing a user’s session information.
> - [Spring Session Management](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/session-mgmt.html) is just a HTTP session related functonality focused to concurrency control, filtering and authentication strategy and do not work with Redis as is. it works with interfaces only.

Using Spring framework you are using Spring Session. You need only configure it to use Redis as backend as in [official documentation sample](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#httpsession-redis) and [sample project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session) with Redis session in spring application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot, then the changes you need for your application is pretty simple.

Add the following dependencies and add redis connection configuration in application.properties and you are good to go.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I have a details post about this at https://springhow.com/spring-boot-security/session-redis/